# Deleting a row from joined tables using group by and having clauses

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mariadb, sql-delete

I want to delete a row from both table (enrol, course) if there are less than 3 enrolees of that course.

```
DELETE enrol, course
FROM enrol
INNER JOIN course
ON enrol.course_id = course.id
WHERE enrol.course_id in (SELECT enrol.course_id group by enrol.course_id having count(*)<3)
```

Instead of deleting the course with less than 3 enrolees, it deletes ALL of my data. I don't know what is wrong with this, please help.

Table 'course':
[image]

Table 'enrol':
[image]

```
SELECT enrol.course_id, course.id
FROM enrol
INNER JOIN course
ON enrol.course_id = course.id
group by enrol.course_id having count(*)<3
```

output: [image]

Desired Output:
All rows within enrol.course_id and course.id with value the same with above output should be deleted.

Comment: can you share your sample input and output tables? @Jadey

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the subquery:

```
SELECT enrol.course_id group by enrol.course_id having count(*)<3
```

which, although is missing a `FROM` clause, it runs without a syntax error in MySql, but produces unexpected results.

Join the correct version of that subquery to the 2 tables like this:

```
DELETE c, e
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN enrol e ON e.course_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) count FROM enrol GROUP BY course_id) t
ON t.course_id = c.id
WHERE e.course_id IS NULL OR t.count < 3;
```

I use `LEFT` joins so that even courses with no enrolees will be deleted.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9ea920a9e23010f25223a89633db638).

Comment: Thank you so much! the query you provided works!